# How to debug kernel crash on /sbin/init during bootup?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, powerpc

I am trying to update the kernel

- from 3.2 to 4.12.  This is  a custom kernel for a Power PC based
  architecture 32 bits.

Here are the problems I am facing.
The kernel boot parameters are passed from Uboot.
I see that the kernel crashes on SyS_selec() . I feel that this print is coming from the interrupt. The kernel log message doesn't tell me much it says something about FPU i.e. Floating point unit. I don't understand why it says FPU since I am not doing anything related to Floating point. Here are the logs. Could you please help me to understand the root cause and where I should look to fix this problem?

```
=> boot
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at f8100000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-4.12.28-disco-standard
   Created:      2019-07-15   4:32:40 UTC
   Image Type:   PowerPC Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    3804492 Bytes = 3.6 MiB
   Load Address: 00000000
   Entry Point:  00000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at f8000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0xf8000000
   Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 007fb000, end 007ff8e8 ... OK

Linux version 4.12.28-disco-standard (oe-user@oe-host) (gcc version 7.3.0 (GCC) ) #1 Mon Jul 15 04:01:31 UTC 2019
Using abcl machine description
bootconsole [udbg0] enabled
-----------------------------------------------------
Hash_size         = 0x0
phys_mem_size     = 0x20000000
dcache_bsize      = 0x20
icache_bsize      = 0x20
cpu_features      = 0x0000000000020460
  possible        = 0x0000000005a6fd77
  always          = 0x0000000000020000
cpu_user_features = 0x8c000000 0x00000000
mmu_features      = 0x00210000
-----------------------------------------------------
abcl_setup_arch()
Zone ranges:
  DMA      [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001fffffff]
  Normal   empty
Movable zone start for each node
Early memory node ranges
  node   0: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001fffffff]
Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001fffffff]
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 130048
Kernel command line: ubi.mtd=1 rootfstype=ubifs root=ubi0:discofs rw console=ttyS1,115200 serno=91101316 sku=700064090C hwrev==00:90:5E:12:32:05 mac1=00:90:5E:12:32:06 mac2=00:90:5E:12:32:07 mac3=00:90:5E:12:32:08 mac4=00:90:5E:12:32:09
PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
Memory: 511900K/524288K available (6004K kernel code, 276K rwdata, 1196K rodata, 192K init, 133K bss, 12388K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
Kernel virtual memory layout:
  * 0xfffdf000..0xfffff000  : fixmap
  * 0xfdffe000..0xfe000000  : early ioremap
  * 0xe1000000..0xfdffe000  : vmalloc & ioremap
NR_IRQS:512 nr_irqs:512 16
IPIC (128 IRQ sources) at e1000700
clocksource: timebase: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x12049cd416, max_idle_ns: 440795202745 ns
clocksource: timebase mult[ccccccd] shift[24] registered
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
devtmpfs: initialized
clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes)
NET: Registered protocol family 16
PCI: Probing PCI hardware
Freescale Elo series DMA driver
vgaarb: loaded
SCSI subsystem initialized
pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
PTP clock support registered
clocksource: Switched to clocksource timebase
NET: Registered protocol family 2
TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)

NET: Registered protocol family 1

RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.

RPC: Registered udp transport module.

RPC: Registered tcp transport module.

RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.

fsl-elo-dma e00082a8.dma: #0 (fsl,elo-dma-channel), irq 71

fsl-elo-dma e00082a8.dma: #1 (fsl,elo-dma-channel), irq 71

fsl-elo-dma e00082a8.dma: #2 (fsl,elo-dma-channel), irq 71

fsl-elo-dma e00082a8.dma: #3 (fsl,elo-dma-channel), irq 71

workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=17 bucket_order=0

NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type

Key type id_resolver registered

Key type id_legacy registered

jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) © 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.

SGI XFS with security attributes, no debug enabled

io scheduler noop registered

io scheduler deadline registered

io scheduler cfq registered (default)

Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing disabled

serial8250.0: ttyS0 at MMIO 0xe0004500 (irq = 16, base_baud = 19531250) is a 16550A

serial8250.0: ttyS1 at MMIO 0xe0004600 (irq = 17, base_baud = 19531250) is a 16550A

console [ttyS1] enabled

console [ttyS1] enabled

bootconsole [udbg0] disabled

bootconsole [udbg0] disabled

brd: module loaded

loop: module loaded

f8000000.flash: Found 1 x16 devices at 0x0 in 16-bit bank. Manufacturer ID 0x000089 Chip ID 0x008966

Intel/Sharp Extended Query Table at 0x010A

Intel/Sharp Extended Query Table at 0x010A

Intel/Sharp Extended Query Table at 0x010A

Intel/Sharp Extended Query Table at 0x010A

Intel/Sharp Extended Query Table at 0x010A

Using buffer write method

Using auto-unlock on power-up/resume

cfi_cmdset_0001: Erase suspend on write enabled

Searching for RedBoot partition table in f8000000.flash at offset 0x7fe0000

No RedBoot partition table detected in f8000000.flash

nand: device found, Manufacturer ID: 0x20, Chip ID: 0xd3

nand: ST Micro NAND08GW3B2CN6

nand: 1024 MiB, SLC, erase size: 128 KiB, page size: 2048, OOB size: 64

Bad block table found at page 524224, version 0x01

Bad block table found at page 524160, version 0x01

nand_read_bbt: bad block at 0x0000023a0000

nand_read_bbt: bad block at 0x0000369c0000

Searching for RedBoot partition table in c0000000.flash at offset 0x3ff60000

No RedBoot partition table detected in c0000000.flash

1 ofpart partitions found on MTD device c0000000.flash

Creating 1 MTD partitions on "c0000000.flash":

0x000000000000-0x000040000000 : "NAND Filesystem"

eLBC NAND device at 0xc0000000, bank 4

abcl nand: no system info node found, assuming legacy device tree blob.

libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed

libphy: Freescale PowerQUICC MII Bus: probed

libphy: Freescale PowerQUICC MII Bus: probed

fsl-gianfar e0025000.ethernet: enabled errata workarounds, flags: 0x4

fsl-gianfar e0025000.ethernet eth0: mac: 00:90:5e:12:32:05

fsl-gianfar e0025000.ethernet eth0: Running with NAPI enabled

fsl-gianfar e0025000.ethernet eth0: RX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256

fsl-gianfar e0025000.ethernet eth0: TX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256

fsl-gianfar e0024000.ethernet: enabled errata workarounds, flags: 0x4

fsl-gianfar e0024000.ethernet eth1: mac: 00:90:5e:12:32:06

fsl-gianfar e0024000.ethernet eth1: Running with NAPI enabled

fsl-gianfar e0024000.ethernet eth1: RX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256

fsl-gianfar e0024000.ethernet eth1: TX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256

i2c /dev entries driver

mpc-i2c e0003000.i2c: timeout 1000000 us

rtc-ds1307: probe of 0-0068 failed with error -5

mpc-i2c e0003100.i2c: timeout 1000000 us

NET: Registered protocol family 17

NET: Registered protocol family 15

8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8

Key type dns_resolver registered

ubi0: attaching mtd1

random: fast init done

ubi0: scanning is finished

ubi0 warning: ubi_eba_init: cannot reserve enough PEBs for bad PEB handling, reserved 108, need 154

ubi0: attached mtd1 (name "NAND Filesystem", size 1024 MiB)

ubi0: PEB size: 131072 bytes (128 KiB), LEB size: 129024 bytes

ubi0: min./max. I/O unit sizes: 2048/2048, sub-page size 512

ubi0: VID header offset: 512 (aligned 512), data offset: 2048

ubi0: good PEBs: 8186, bad PEBs: 6, corrupted PEBs: 0

ubi0: user volume: 3, internal volumes: 1, max. volumes count: 128

ubi0: max/mean erase counter: 2/0, WL threshold: 4096, image sequence number: 2015956448

ubi0: available PEBs: 0, total reserved PEBs: 8186, PEBs reserved for bad PEB handling: 108

ubi0: background thread "ubi_bgt0d" started, PID 82

hctosys: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)

of_cfs_init

of_cfs_init: OK

md: Waiting for all devices to be available before autodetect

md: If you don't use raid, use raid=noautodetect

md: Autodetecting RAID arrays.

md: autorun ...

md: ... autorun DONE.

UBIFS (ubi0:0): background thread "ubifs_bgt0_0" started, PID 87

UBIFS (ubi0:0): recovery needed

UBIFS (ubi0:0): recovery completed

UBIFS (ubi0:0): UBIFS: mounted UBI device 0, volume 0, name "discofs"

UBIFS (ubi0:0): LEB size: 129024 bytes (126 KiB), min./max. I/O unit sizes: 2048 bytes/2048 bytes
UBIFS (ubi0:0): FS size: 198567936 bytes (189 MiB, 1539 LEBs), journal size 9033728 bytes (8 MiB, 71 LEBs)
UBIFS (ubi0:0): reserved for root: 0 bytes (0 KiB)
UBIFS (ubi0:0): media format: w4/r0 (latest is w5/r0), UUID C7F7CF25-F51C-4F98-878F-489AD5ECB0E4, small LPT model
VFS: Mounted root (ubifs filesystem) on device 0:13.
devtmpfs: mounted
Freeing unused kernel memory: 192K
This architecture does not have kernel memory protection.
Unable to handle kernel paging request for data at address 0x00005091
Faulting instruction address: 0xc0100eec
Oops: Kernel access of bad area, sig: 11 [#1]
abcl
Modules linked in:
CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 4.12.28-disco-standard #1
task: df416a60 task.stack: df42a000
NIP: c0100eec LR: c01013a0 CTR: 00000000
REGS: df42be40 TRAP: 0300   Not tainted  (4.12.28-disco-standard)
MSR: 00009032 <EE,ME,IR,DR,RI>
  CR: 22002442  XER: 00000000
DAR: 00005091 DSISR: 20000000
GPR00: c0101350 df42bef0 df416a60 df42bef8 bfccbb94 00000000 00000000 00000000
GPR08: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10028254 00000000 00000000
GPR16: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
GPR24: bfcccf47 00000000 00000000 00000000 bfccbb08 0000000c bfccbb90 df42bef8
NIP [c0100eec] poll_select_set_timeout+0x0/0x174
LR [c01013a0] SyS_select+0x9c/0x114
Call Trace:
[df42bef0] [c0101350] SyS_select+0x4c/0x114 (unreliable)
[df42bf40] [c00103a8] ret_from_syscall+0x0/0x38
--- interrupt: c01 at 0xfef65b4
    LR = 0xfef657c
Instruction dump:
28f5c8c2 57ff803e 87d89261 f55d3806 7d37c1cf eac5d8a5 24dbd73d 532e2514
e4b43b1b e77c9e25 cefebc5b 76ac3b5f <adba5091> 1d7f7395 3cfdc277 8d7c18a0
---[ end trace 0bfbbaf2a7935445 ]---

Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b

Rebooting in 180 seconds..
```

Comment: Are you trying to bring-up a custom board or is it a comercial one? Does it crash at the same point between consecutive boot ups?

Comment: yes, its a custom board. Yes, it crashes at the same point between consecutive boot ups. What's the reason for asking this question like consistent crash points?

Comment: Add `ignore_loglevel` to the kernel command line and post a link to the messages you will get till the crash.

Comment: can you upload full boot log will be helpful answering? also if you know exact kernel version like 4.12.14 do mention.

Comment: Updated the full boot log. I feel that the last logs are coming .S file which is written in assembly. I don't understand why do I get FPU error - I am not doing anything related to floating points. I am very surprised on why it says something like that. Also, I am very unsure now on how to go further and where to debug and check. Like what should be the next call?

Comment: It seems you have unhandled #PF.

Comment: (1) *"The kernel log message ... says something about FPU i.e. Floating point unit."* -- Where is that message?  I see nothing about a *"FPU"* in the log.  Are you confusing "fault" with "float"? (2) What is in that old UBIFS?  (3) How was the old 3.2 kernel built compared to this 4.12? Did you change the toolchain and libC?

Comment: The only difference I see between working and non-working is - VFS: Mounted root (ubifs filesystem) on device 0:12 and in my case it is VFS: Mounted root (ubifs filesystem) on device 0:13. I thought it is just a minor number, does it matter? If yes, how to change this. I thought it is dynamically assigned. Am I correct? Also, what is the meaning of exitcode=0x00000006 from kill init?

Comment: Does the fail always happen at "_Unable to handle kernel paging request for data at address 0x00005091
Faulting instruction address: 0xc0100eec_" addresses?

Comment: no, I have put some prints in the traps.c and now I see the Oops: Exception in NIP [c0100b24] do_fcntl+0x0/0x41c
LR [c0101144] SyS_fcntl64+0x88/0x14c
Call Trace:
[df42bf10] [df416a60] 0xdf416a60 (unreliable)
[df42bf40] [c0010428] ret_from_syscall+0x0/0x38
--- interrupt: c01 at 0xfeea754
    LR = 0xfeea8c0
Instruction dump:
9b72287b c5097  20bcee23 25023b23
6c37f000 e75cec6b b5b1afcc 59234962 <f4d180c9> f11f42ac ab0aba42 6efedb48
---[ end trace 7948ae3a1df3fa67 ]---
S..Crashing from here.. Passed oops_end 198
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000004

Answer (score -1):

You haven't mentioned what kind of initramfs you use. Can you try adding "break=init" to your kernel commandline options to see if you get a shell?

Comment: What is meant by kind of initramfs?

Comment: What I mean is, it is based on debian, yocto, buildroot, etc. Each has a slightly different set of scripts for bootstrapping the system.

Comment: It is based out of Yocto.

Comment: Try adding "init=/bin/bash" or "init=/bin/sh" to the kernel commandline to see if it succeeds.